# Different styles based on Operative System

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, operating-system

i have a problem with my webapp

Im using tomcat 6 + jr6 in Windows 10 and Windows 2003 Server, the problem is that when i use Windows 2003 Server for loading the app it doesnt apply the same styles as in Windows 2010 (pics down), i have problems downloading files from the server too (only in Internet Explorer and with the app in Windows 2003 Server)

Also in Windows 2003 Server jsps seems to load much slower than Windows 2010 (same machine different SO)

**PS. I have used Windows 2010 internet explorer for all tests**

The question is, is that possible ?

I thought that only java version and tomcat version applys to this

Windows 2003 Server + Tomcat 6 + JRE6 + Internet Explorer

[image]

Windows 2010 + Tomcat 6 + JRE6 + Internet Explorer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just how web browsers work: they have their own default styles and if you don't override them, you get the defaults.

The biggest difference I see between your two screenshots is the shape of the "Guardar Escritura" button at the bottom: in the above image, the button has square corners and in the image below it has rounded corners.

You have full control over button display using CSS. It looks like you need to add some more styles to your stylesheet to ensure that your page looks the same on all platforms.

Note that most MSIE/Edge versions have similar defaults. You may be surprised when you load your page in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari.

Comment: I agree with you, but here the problem is not using 2 different browsers, they were both screenshots from same browser, same tomcat version and same java version. Only the SO wich launchs tomcat is the difference (2003 Server vs 2010)

Comment: The Java and Tomcat versions are irrelevant: the browser is rendering the page based upon the HTML that was provided. When you say "SO" do you mean "OS", like "Operating System"? If so, then you almost certain have different versions of the browser with different defaults.

Comment: I mean Operative System, i was using 2 tabs from Windows 10 Internet Explorer, one for Windows 2010 webapp and one for Windows 2003 Server webapp. Also i have problems with  Windows 2003 Server webapp downloading files (only in IE)

Comment: So you are saying that the same application running (server side) on Windows 2003 looks different than that same application running (server side) on Windows 2010 (which, by the way, does not exist) but with the same exact client OS and browser?

Comment: Yes, i know you should think im crazy but im not. This is exactly same webapp, tomcat and java in server side and also web browser in client side. Only OS makes here the difference.